# LINQ to SQL - multiple result and access to data

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I do not know how to get to the data with LINQ to SQL query that returns many records. Suppose the following code returns 4 results. How to get the id and pesel with a second record?

```
public class DaneOsoboweGet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
    public string Imie { get; set; }
    public int PESEL { get; set; }
    public string  Ulica { get; set; }
    public string  Miasto { get; set; }
    public string KodPocztowy { get; set; }
}

baza_back_clasesDataContext dt = new baza_back_clasesDataContext();
var osoby = from k in dt.tblOsoby
    where k.Nazwisko == "Kowalski"
    select new DaneOsoboweGet
    {
        Id = k.id,
        Nazwisko = k.nazwisko,
        Imie = k.imie,
        PESEL = k.pesel,
        Ulica = k.ulica,
        Miasto = k.miasto,
        KodPocztowy = k.kodpocztowy,
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you having problems paging through the data in your interface or what?

Comment: are you asking how to gets specific index record like 2nd 3rd after getting rows from your LINQ TO SQL query `osoby `

Comment: yes, I ask how to get for example to second record and retrieve only id and pesel and keep them as variables. sorry for english ;)

Comment: @Paweł - Please explain what you want to do with the data from the query. That will help us understand how to help you

Comment: for examle I need to get id from multiple results of this query to find related records in another table. The search is when I open a new window, the searched results is taked 'id' from the first record, then searching for the record in the second table on the basis of the first 'id' and displays the data in textboxs when pressed a next button is taken 'id' from the second record, then searching for the record in the second table on the basis of the first 'id' and displays the data in textboxs and so on. When you push the button back 'id' is taken from a previous record...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var mylist = osoby.ToList();

Will this work?

myList[1] should be the 2nd record.

Comment: myList[1] should be the 2nd record if it exists